# @Autowired not working for repositories in Spring-Data (NullPointerException)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, nullpointerexception, spring-data

I have a java(9.0.4) project where I have included spring-data.

Dependencies in pom.xml:

```html
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>9.4.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.21</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

Конфигуратор:

```java
import org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;

import java.util.Properties;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan("ru.tenderwin")
@EnableJpaRepositories("ru.tenderwin")
public class DataConfig {

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource TWDataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.class.getName());
        dataSource.setUrl("url");
        dataSource.setUsername("name");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emFactory.setDataSource(TWDataSource());
        emFactory.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
        emFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        //jpaProperties.setProperty("show_sql", "true");
        //jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect");
        //jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.current_session_context_class", "thread");
        //jpaProperties.setProperty("hibernate.format_sql", "true");

        emFactory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
        emFactory.setPackagesToScan("ru.tenderwin");

        return  emFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

Essence:

```java
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
@Table(schema = "Schema")
public class Clients {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String ID;
    @Column
    private String Name;
    @Column
    private Timestamp RegistrationDate;

    public Clients() {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Clients{" +
                "ID='" + ID + '\'' +
                ", Name='" + Name + '\'' +
                ", RegistrationDate=" + RegistrationDate +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Repository:

```java
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import ru.tenderwin.TWdata.models.TWIdentity.Clients;

public interface ClientsRepository extends CrudRepository<Clients,String> {

}
```

I'm trying to pull data from the database into an entity and enter this into the console:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import ru.tenderwin.TWdata.repositories.TWIdentity.ClientsRepository;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = DataConfig.class)
@Transactional
public class Main {

    @Autowired
    public ClientsRepository clientsRepository;

    @Test
    void testers() {
        System.out.println(
                clientsRepository.findById("DE39596D-2890-4D91-BE24-000D480190AE")
        );
    }
    
}
```

This results in an error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
> at ru.tenderwin.Main.testers(Main.java:20)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
> at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
> at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1380)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1380)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
> at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
> at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
> at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38)
> at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235)
> at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54)

Process finished with exit code -1

but, interestingly, if you display the entity by requesting the repository from the context, then there will be no problems:

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import ru.tenderwin.TWdata.DataConfig;
import ru.tenderwin.TWdata.repositories.TWIdentity.ClientsRepository;

@ContextConfiguration(classes = DataConfig.class)
@Transactional
public class Main {

    @Test
    void testers() {
        ApplicationContext context = new
                AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DataConfig.class);


        System.out.println(
                context.getBean(ClientsRepository.class).
                        findById("DE39596D-2890-4D91-BE24-000D480190AE")
        );
    }

}
```

Our client is displayed in the console:

> Optional[Clients{ID='DE39596D-2890-4D91-BE24-000D480190AE', Name='Неизвестный клиент', RegistrationDate=2022-02-06 07:24:10.8759664}]

I can’t figure out at all why @Autowired doesn’t work for my Repositories

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! All content posted on this site is required to be in English only. Please translate your post.